# What is wrong with Http security header (X-XSS-Protection, X-Content-Type-Options) on my website/server?

Tags: security

I really do not know what is wrong but https security headers works wel with http but not with https on my site. I have set via htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always append X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header always append X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

and when i test my website this is result:

> > > http://www.mywebsite.com

```
> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:33:49 GMT
Server: Apache
X-XSS-Protection:   1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options:    SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location:   https://www.www.mywebsite.com/
Ip: 162.252.xx.xx
Cache-Control:  max-age=2592000
Expires:    Sat, 29 Jan 2022 12:33:49 GMT
Content-Length: 242
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

> > > https://www.mywebsite.com

```
> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 200 OK
Code:   200
Date:   Thu, 30 Dec 2021 12:33:49 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html
```

So you can see that security headers X-XSS-Protection, X-Frame-Options and X-Content-Type-Options are set and sent by accessing url via http://www.mywebsite.com but with https://www.mywebsite.com not.

Why it works via http protocol and not via https protocol? Where is issue? What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using these lines ....

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```